# File class works bad on OS X because of encoding issue

Tags: java, macos, encoding, character-encoding

My OS X's default charset is "UTF-8", which is the same as my Java project's I'm working on. The problem is that the File class and some of its methods just don't function correctly when the path contains Chinese characters. (Generally it takes 3 bytes to represent a Chinese character in unicode)

For example, I firstly initiate a String variable = "xxx", where "xxx" is a valid path that contains Chinese characters. After that I create a File object by new File(prevStringVar). And when exists() method is called, it always return false.

It's more wired when calling the listFiles() method.

I think the problem would be solved, if Charset could be specified when instanciate a File object, like, constructor File(String path, Charset charset).

Answer (score 1):

Simply calling the method as **file = new File("afile")** creates an Instance of the File Object within your Java Code. This does not actually create a File in your filesystem, until you write something to it, and flush the buffer (closing will flush the buffer).

Try doing this with a plain english word, like "afile", rather than including Chinese characters. This will eliminate the issue of character-encoding. Once you have it working there, then change the filename, and see if your problem is resolved.

Comment: To phrase this differently: a `File` doesn't represent an actual file on the disk. It's an abstraction over a *filesystem path*, that allows us to call various operations that work over paths. (Like checking whether an actual file exists at that path.)